# How to change Border Background image programmatically

Tags: wpf, border, imagebrush

I am creating a media player app in WPF c#.
I am using Media Element to do this.

Anyways, I have used `<Border> </Border>` to add border some places.

```
    <Border Name="hej1">
                <Border.Background>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images\music.png"  Stretch="None"/>
                </Border.Background>

                <MediaElement ..../> 
    </Border>
```

I want to change the ImageSource to some other picture programmatically, how to do that?

I have tried but no success.

So for every song the image in `<ImageBrush ImageSource="Images\music.png"` is changed.

Thanks in advance

Shafi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign a Name to the ImageBrush:

```
<ImageBrush x:Name="imageBrush" ImageSource="Images\music.png" Stretch="None"/>
```

Then use the named member in code:

```
var filename = @"Images\title.png";
imageBrush.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(filename, UriKind.Relative));
```

---

Or simply cast the value of the Border's `Background` property to type ImageBrush:

```
var imageBrush = (ImageBrush)hej1.Background;
var filename = @"Images\title.png";
imageBrush.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(filename, UriKind.Relative));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Images\myimage.png"));
ImageBrush image = new ImageBrush();
image.ImageSource = img;
Border.Background =image;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void SetBackgroundForControl(Control control, string ImageFileName, string ImageDir = "Images")
    {
        var imageBrush = new ImageBrush(); 
        var filename = Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, ImageDir, ImageFileName);
        imageBrush.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(filename, UriKind.Relative));
        control.Background = imageBrush;
    }
```